# Why client need a new build instead of just download the released executable

Tags: operating-systems, libraries, build, binary-files

The question is **just a sentence**, why the github projects would always like to come with the build instructions instead of just leaving the download link/instruction? I personally think that it implicitly indicating that the built/released version of .exe is **not stable enough** or developers omitted the minority of devices that problem may occurred.

I doing research on solo mining and no, not joining any mining pool.
But at the time I approached to the CPUMiner, I found that there's a download link and also the build instructions. Anyway, it took hours for me to understand what really the "Build" stand for ([build guidelines in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBEsa.png)).

Comment: 1) Building you a release exe is a pain.  It doesn't come for free producing a release and posting it for your enjoyment. 2) The thing you show is for LINUX, NOT WINDOWS making it even less stable still.. and a bigger PITA to build.  IMHO, you should try using WSL to build and run this code.. you might find that there are even release binaries for you on the Linux side.  You can run these DIRECTLY under WSL without a custom "franken-build".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is just a sentence, why the github projects would always like to come with the build instructions instead of just leaving the download link/instruction?

The primary purpose of GitHub is to host *source code.* The ability to publish final .exe files is just something they added on the side, for convenience. But when you visit any GitHub project, you're really visiting its source code repository and viewing its README specifically.

So because you're browsing the source files of a program, it's quite natural that they will come with instructions for building those files into a program – otherwise they would be quite useless if nobody knew how to use them.

(The reasons why the developers would publish the program's source code in the first place are best discussed elsewhere.)